# Como saber se a conexão com banco de dados esta correta PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou a 16 horas tentando fazer uma conexão com banco de dados dar certo e não estou conseguindo, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, atualmente estou usando o xampp, e estou trabalhando para um cliente que precisa acessar o banco de dados de uma forma relativamente simples, e essa conexão não desenrola.

```
    $_POST['botao'];
$nivel = $_POST['depressao'];


$servername = "localhost";
echo $servername;
$database = "test";
echo $database;
$username = "root";
echo $username;
$password = ""; 
echo $password;

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection

$query = "insert into triste (depressao) values ({$nivel})";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);
mysqli_close();

?>


<form action="conexao.php">
  <input name="depressao" />
  <button type="submit" name="botao"></button>
</form
```

>

Sim eu troquei o banco de dados pra uma tabela e um db de testes, pra forçar alguns erros fora de produção, e o banco de dados simplesmente não conecta, já tentei fazer essa conexão de varias formas, não sei o que fazer, estou quase trocando pra node.js. que apesar de não saber muito, pelo menos tenho conhecimento em Js, sei la to perdido de verdade. quem puder me dar uma luz fico grato!

Comment: `if (!$conn) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit(); }` .. [Veja a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Se tentar conectar com esses parâmetros da linha de comando o que acontece?

Comment: Não acontece nada , ele simplesmente ignora todo o código php que é escrito. e fazendo uns teste hoje, descobri que esse código ta indo comentado no console. O codigo ta sendo comentado inteiro com comentario no Html gerado da pagina <!---->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito tempo, procurando como resolver esse problema, e descobri, que a falha não estava no código em si, e sim em um arquivo, `.htaccess`  que estava impedindo que o servidor encontrasse o caminho para a pasta do PHP.  agradeço aos quem tentaram ajudar